# What's wrong with my gpu?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, intel

I decided to update my drivers and i checked the internet, then i tried to do the same but when i write that;

```
$ lspci -vnn | grep -i VGA -A 12
```

i get these in both ways:

[image: nvidia]

[image: intel]

i really don't know why can't i use nvidia can somebody help and explain what happens?  i'm pretty sure i have nvidia GeForce 840M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the GPU.
You just chose the wrong command.
You have to execute this command :

```
lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'
```

The output gives you something like :

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device 3501
Kernel driver in use: i915  

01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 860M] (rev a2)
Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device 3501
Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

Comment: Yes, you are right! Thanks for answer. Btw can you help me how to update my drivers if you know how?

Comment: I opened new question can you check it please? http://askubuntu.com/q/740093/512218