# How to update additional driver (Nvidia GPU and CPU)

Tags: drivers, cpu, gpu, additional-drivers

Firstly i want my drivers up to date. So can you help me about that? And 1 more question, at CPU title we have 2 options like microwaves and do not use device. Which one i must use? I use that right now:

[image]

Comment: All the recommended drivers are installed. You do not need to do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you mean security updates - you will receive them for the drivers that you have installed from the Ubuntu repositories. When you want feature updates, you have to install new drivers from the Proprietary GPU Drivers PPA ... the latest official NVIDIA drivers currently are 361.28.

It is recommended to use the drivers from the repositories. When you nevertheless want to install the newer drivers from the NVIDIA long-lived branch ... open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-361 nvidia-prime
sudo reboot
```

Processor microcode contains updated system processor microcode for
Intel x64 x86 processors.
Intel releases microcode updates to correct processor behavior as documented in the respective processor specification updates. It is not necessary to use these drivers - but you can if you want.

Comment: Maybe enough posting the same answer a few times a day?

Comment: idk it is same answer or not but it is helpful. really thank you mate :) you recommend microcode or other option for better performance etc.?

Comment: @Alp : You're welcome ... and ... no it is not the same answer ... it is slightly different ... many new users ask questions about NVIDIA graphics, so I just try to help them ... mostly there is something different, because every hardware and every setup is different. I have quite new hardware, so I have the latest official drivers installed. On my machine the NVIDIA drivers 361 work great without any issues and I have intel-microcode activated as well ... but in the end ... this decision is up to you ... and now ... enjoy ubuntu experience ! :)

Comment: can you help me at my new question? : http://askubuntu.com/questions/745096/cant-change-resolution?noredirect=1#comment1109225_745096

Comment: ok, but i was triying to do what other guy said, but my pc doesnt even open :O

Comment: After i purged all nvidia drivers it sucks at gnome black screen

Comment: 47.877606 dem:gen8_irq_handler i915 <error> the master control interrupt lied (sde)!

Comment: İ tried but no, again it comes to gnome black screen and stops here

Comment: İ cant upload photos because i am on phone

Comment: Sorry man, i can do nothing. It stops at black screen and says: mid kermel crash signatures

Comment: @Alp : There seems to be more broken than the graphics drivers - you should consider to reinstall the system and after that first install the NVIDIA drivers ! :)

Comment: My all files will be gone right?

Comment: @Alp : Yes - but you can copy them to another drive from the ubuntu installation media before installing. :)

Comment: i saw something now, everycode was (OK) and look at that: ( **) (3 of 4) A start job is running for LSB : start samba daemons for the AD DC (44s/5min 30s) [OK] started restore sound cart state