# Can't change resolution!

Tags: nvidia, settings, display-resolution

I have installed Nvidia's last driver, applied and rebooted my PC. Then after reboot. My resolution came with 640x480 there is no other options to change it in either nvidia x server or display settings. I really don't know what happened, can you help me please asap?

Comment: i've already installed 361 how they show me at past question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/740093/how-to-update-additional-driver-nvidia-gpu-and-cpu

Comment: nvidia geforce 840m

Comment: okey, trying that

Comment: @cl-netbox See my comment on Ashu's answer, it is a exact copy paste of one you gave to him.

Comment: Go to recovery mode https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode and follow the answer by cl-netbox

Comment: @markkirby : my files will be deleted?

Comment: No, why would they? Recovery is like Windows safe mode.

Comment: @markkirby and cl-netbox ; i really appreciate your helps. i did the recovery mode installed the 361 then it come up! thanks guys really! i wanna ask 1 more thing . "vboxclient the virtualbox kernel service is not running. exiting." i get that error when i logged in any solutions?

Comment: Please accept cl-netbox answer if it worked with the check mark on the left. If you have another question please ask a new one as this is a Q/A site we like one question a post to keep it simple :)

Answer (score 2):

Completely remove all the NVIDIA software you have installed and reinstall the NVIDIA drivers.
Because you have the 361 drivers installed - you do not need to add the GPU Drivers PPA again.

Highlight the Ubuntu menu entry and  press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line.
Press the <kbd>F10</kbd> key to boot into the Ubuntu system.

Open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo reboot
```

After the restart ...

Highlight the Ubuntu menu entry and  press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line.
Press the <kbd>F10</kbd> key to boot into the Ubuntu system.

Open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-361 nvidia-prime
sudo reboot
```