# Resolution stuck at 640x480 (NVIDIA Quadro K3000M)

Tags: display-resolution

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.3. I attempted to install WINE using Ubuntu Software. After it installed nothing happened when I clicked launch. I then restarted my system and found that my display was stuck at 640x480. I tried removing WINE but this did not solve anything. When I go change the resolution in my settings there are no options.

EDIT: My Graphics card is an NVIDIA Quadro K3000M. When I go into the system profiler and benchmark I see that no graphics card appears to be recognized. It only says:

```
640x480
(Unknown)
The X.Org Foundation
```

I also tried `xrandr` and get the following:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 480, current 640 x 480, maximum 640 x 480
default connected primary 640x480+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   640x480       73.00*
```

And with inxi:

`inxi -SMG -! 31 -y 80
System:    Kernel: 5.3.0-26-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: Gnome 3.28.4
           Distro: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Machine:   Device: laptop System: Hewlett-Packard product: HP EliteBook 8770w v: A1019DD202 serial: N/A
           Mobo: Hewlett-Packard model: 176C v: KBC Version 50.1B serial: N/A
           BIOS: Hewlett-Packard v: 68IAV Ver. F.41 date: 05/20/2013
Graphics:  Card: NVIDIA GK104GLM [Quadro K3000M]
           Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.20.4 )
           drivers: fbdev,nouveau (unloaded: modesetting,vesa)
           Resolution: 640x480@73.00hz
           OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 8.0, 256 bits)
           version: 3.3 Mesa 19.0.8`

It appears that everything is installed?

`sudo ubuntu-drivers install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 34 not upgraded.`

Comment: When dealing with graphic issues, you will need to include your system specifications in your question. Many graphical issues are very much related to the type of graphical card you have.

Comment: Also, with the new `5.3.0-26-generic` kernel that comes with the HWE for 18.04.3, the NVIDIA drivers do not compile into the new kernel automatically.  I had to get the output of `dkms status` and see if my video driver was installed into the kernel.  It was installed into the old, but not the new.

Comment: Add the system info `inxi -SMG -! 31 -y 80`, try `sudo ubuntu-drivers install`, did you try to `xrandr -s 0`?

Comment: `xrandr -s 0` doesn't appear to do anything.

Comment: What is the output of `dkms status`?  And add that to your question.  I am really wondering if your driver did not get installed into the new kernel.  If it did not, the command would be like the following (this example is doing the newest NVIDIA driver that is installed on a system):  `sudo dkms install nvidia/440.48.02 -k 5.3.0-26-generic`

Comment: I actually managed to solve the issue by following the instructions of cl-netbox here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/745096/cant-change-resolution?rq=1  It does appear that I just did not have my drivers installed properly. I'm not sure what exactly WINE did to further worsen the issue. Thanks everyone for taking the time to offer advice.